# Get String Array from Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database with 45 different entries, each with:

```
public static final String TABLE = "Table";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_HOUR = "hour";
public static final String COLUMN_WEEK = "week";
public static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_COLOUR = "colour";
public static final String COLUMN_ROOM = "room";
```

now I want to read out all. I Do this with following:

```
public Cursor fetchAllSubject(){
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE, new String[] {
            COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_HOUR, COLUMN_WEEK, COLUMN_DAY, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, COLUMN_COLOUR, COLUMN_ROOM},null
            , null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

In a other class I have this code to read all out:

```
dao = new DAO(this);
Cursor subjectList = dao.fetchAllSubject();
```

Now I want to have for each entry an array with ID, Hour, week, ... but I have no idea how to do that.
My first try was following:

```
ArrayList<String> mo1h = new ArrayList<String>();
subjectList.moveToFirst();
while(!subjectList.isAfterLast()) {
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_ID)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_HOUR)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_WEEK)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_DAY)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_NAME)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_COLOUR)));
     mo1h.add(subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_ROOM)));     
     subjectList.moveToNext();
}
```

But everything is in mo1h, and I dont know how to devide it.
The best would be to have a String[] for each. Has anybody an Idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create on **Bean class** and then create one **ArrayList** (Collection class)

```
public class Bean
{
   public Bean();
   String id, hour, week, day, name, description, color, room;
}
```

now create list of Bean

```
ArrayList<Bean> mo1h = new ArrayList<Bean>();
subjectList.moveToFirst();
while(!subjectList.isAfterLast()) {
Bean b = new Bean();
   b.id = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_ID));
   b.hour =subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_HOUR));
   ...
   ...
   // all your column
   mo1h.add(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not continue with your strategy, but instead use an ArrayList of String[]:

```
ArrayList<String[]> mo1h = new ArrayList<String[]>();
subjectList.moveToFirst();
while(!subjectList.isAfterLast()) {
     String[] toUse = new String[8];
     toUse[0] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_ID));
     toUse[1] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_HOUR));
     toUse[2] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_WEEK));
     toUse[3] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_DAY));
     toUse[4] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_NAME));
     toUse[5] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION));
     toUse[6] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_COLOUR));
     toUse[7] = subjectList.getString(subjectList.getColumnIndex(dao.COLUMN_ROOM)); 
     mo1h.add(toUse);    
     subjectList.moveToNext();
}
```